# key binding not working tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

This code should make the tank move left when you press the left arrow, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.constants import LEFT
root = Tk()
c = Canvas(root, width=400, height=400)
tank = c.create_rectangle(200,200,250, 250, outline = 'dark green', 
fill='dark green')
c.pack()

class tank:
    def move_left(self):
        c.move(tank, -200, 0)
c.bind('<Left>', tank.move_left(tank))
c.focus_set()            
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why is `move_left` in a class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems here:

- In `c.bind('<Left>', tank.move_left(tank))`, you actually pass the return value of tank.move_left to c.bind second argument ; and that return value is `None`.
- You define a variable called `tank`, and then overwrite that variable with a class called `tank`.

Fixing both issues:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.constants import LEFT
root = Tk()
c = Canvas(root, width=400, height=400)
tank = c.create_rectangle(200,200,250, 250, outline = 'dark green', fill='dark green')
c.pack()

class Tank: # Pascal case is the recommended naming convention for classes
    def move_left(self):
        c.move(tank, -200, 0)

c.bind('<Left>', Tank.move_left) # Passing the function and not its return value as 2nd argument
c.focus_set()            
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version based on Reblochon Masque's now-deleted answer. If he posts his own repaired version I'll remove this one.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Battlefield(tk.Canvas):
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        super().__init__(root, width=400, height=400)
        self.pack()

        tank = Tank(self)

        self.bind('<Left>', tank.move)
        self.bind('<Right>', tank.move)
        self.bind('<Up>', tank.move)
        self.bind('<Down>', tank.move)

class Tank:
    OFFSETS = {'Left': (-1, 0), 'Right': (1, 0), 'Up': (0, -1), 'Down': (0, 1)}

    def __init__(self, canvas):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.id = self.canvas.create_rectangle(200, 200, 250, 250, outline='dark green', fill='dark green')

    def move(self, event):
        self.canvas.move(self.id, *Tank.OFFSETS[event.keysym])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    battlefield = Battlefield(root)
    battlefield.focus_set()
    root.mainloop()
```

---

Of course, you don't really need a class for something this simple.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=400, height=400)
canvas.pack()
tank = canvas.create_rectangle(200, 200, 250, 250, outline='dark green', fill='dark green')

OFFSETS = {'Left': (-1, 0), 'Right': (1, 0), 'Up': (0, -1), 'Down': (0, 1)}

def move(event):
    canvas.move(tank, *OFFSETS[event.keysym])

canvas.bind('<Left>', move)
canvas.bind('<Right>', move)
canvas.bind('<Up>', move)
canvas.bind('<Down>', move)
canvas.focus_set()

root.mainloop()
```